# Should I use "whether or not" or "whether" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

Should I use "whether or not" or just "whether" in following sentence? Which one is correct?

> I kept contemplating **whether or not** to sell my stock position.

OR

> I kept contemplating **whether** to sell my stock position.

Comment: Both versions are correct, and there is no difference in meaning between them. *Contemplate*, however, is an odd word here: it suggests dispassionately gazing at the choice rather than actively wrestling with it.

Comment: @StoneyB When it comes to stocks, dispassionate gazing, or even glazed dispassion might not be so uncommon. Until the price suddenly moves, of course. :)

Comment: @StoneyB  I think "contemplate" is fine, but "keep contemplating" is an awkward pairing.  You can contemplate the potential value of an investment, but to *keep* doing so implies, as you say, a much stronger feeling about it.

Answer (score 4):

We often use *whether*-clauses to represent closed questions. This means they often represent questions which have the answer *yes* or *no*.

1. I am wondering [whether I should sell my stock position].

So there are two possible answers to the question *Should I sell my stock position?*: YES and NO.

In English, when a *whether*-clauses represents a closed question, we do not need to represent the *no* option in the clause. (In many other languages you *do* need to represent the *no* option).

However, although we don't represent the *no* option, we *can* if we want to. This does not change the meaning of the sentence at all. There are two ways we can do this:

2. I am wondering [**whether** **or not** I should sell my stock position]
3. I am wondering [**whether**  I should sell my stock position **or not**]

In the first example, we see the words *or not* appearing after the word *whether*. In the second example, these words appear at the end of the clause instead. Both of these examples are grammatical.

In English, sentences (1), (2) and (3) are all grammatical and all mean the  same thing. For this reason both of the Original Poster's examples are grammatical and also have the same meaning.

---

**Grammar note:**

We can also use *whether*-clauses to make special conditionals called *exhaustive conditionals*. When we use *whether*-clauses in conditionals, they MUST include all the possible outcomes of the situation—otherwise they are ungrammatical. Usually this means that they must contain the words *or not*:

- Whether you want to **or not**, you must go to the meeting.
- Whether **or not** you want to, you must go to the meeting.
- *Whether you want to, you must go to the meeting. (ungrammatical)

Comment: +1 Wanna add *if X*, *if X or not*, but usually not *if or not X*?

Comment: @StoneyB The mind is willing, but the time-table is unyielding ...

Comment: What an elegant answer this is! I was searching for this problem and this post came out, and this solves the problem perfectly in such a way a great book would explain.